# Multiple ranges in solr for a regular query

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

How can you have a multiple ranges in a solr query when a normal query (q) is used instead of filter query (fq). I looked at answers in here [Multiple ranges in a facet in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580100/multiple-ranges-in-a-facet-in-solr), but they seem not to work when a normal query is used like this: q=pageviews:([200 TO 250] OR [500 TO 550]), or pageviews:[200 TO 250] OR pageviews:[500 TO 550]. Tried both, but they do not seem to work with the solr I have. One difference I find is that my solr only accepts normal queries instead of filter queries.

Comment: q=pageviews:([200 TO 250] OR [500 TO 550])  this seems to work for me. I used another field in one my Solr servers to test it. What is fieldType for pageviews?

Comment: The type of the field is long. Here's its schema: <field name="example_field" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

Comment: When you say it does not work, do you mean it gives 0 results? or it gives incorrect results? Note that you are doing a range query on a multi valued field. You will probably see results that you are not expecting. Example: <arr name="example_field">
<int>230</int>
<int>1000</int>  . Do you expect this to be in your result? because your first range will match it, but the second one does not.

Comment: When I query with multiple ranges, it gives all the results, as it would if no "last_modified" parameter would be given.

Comment: Also, even the multivalued=true, all the data seems to have only one value, at least according to query results.

Comment: Can you try indexing your data with multivalued=false and then try running the query?