# Solr multiple facets with individual queries or ranges

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a book database. Books have genre ids as integers, and also age ranges in integers age_min and age_max.

When I make a query, I'd like to know 1) a list of distinct genre ids that are in the result and 2) any of those results are between different 1 or more age ranges (0-4, 5-7, etc.).

I'd like a list of genre_ids as well as how many books are for ages 0-4, 5-7, 7-10, and so on.

I can use facet.field for the genre_ids and that works fine, but I cannot figure out to have that in addition to the different age ranges.

My query for JUST genre_id facet looks like this:

http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?wt=json&q=all_genres%3A%22fiction+-+fantasy%22&rows=1&start=0&defType=edismax&facet=true&facet.field=genre_id

So, not only tell me the genre_ids that make up the results but also how many of those books are ages 0-4, 5-7, etc..

Something like:

```
"facet_fields":{
      "genre_id":{
        "38":998,
        "638":915,
      "ages":{
        "0-4":4,
        "5-7":10,
```

and so forth.

Is there a way to get all this information from one solr query?

Comment: For the `ages` facets - have you seen the [Range Faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-RangeFaceting) support?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at that but it's not clear to me how to use it in combination with my genre_id facet. I think I do understand that in order to have multiple facet ranges, for multiple age ranges, I'd have to use keys as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580100/multiple-ranges-in-a-facet-in-solr)

Comment: The "keys" you reference is just the field name. To configure the facet for genre_id, use `f.genre_id.<setting>`. To configure the facet for `ages`, use `f.ages.<setting>` instead of `facet.<setting>`.

Comment: Here's my current query for the genre_id facet:

http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?wt=json&q=all_genres%3A%22fiction+-+fantasy%22&rows=1&start=0&defType=edismax&facet=true&facet.field=genre_id&

If you have the time, how would I alter this to add the ages facet? I tried a few things and they didn't seem to work, I must have something wrong or am misunderstanding how to configure.

Comment: Add something like `facet.field=ages&f.ages.facet.range.start=0&f.ages.facet.range.gap=4` or something similar to get started and to see if it works properly, then start expanding it if you need custom intervals (you could also use facet queries in that case).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983807/how-do-i-correctly-index-spanish-language-documents-using-solr

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking my problem a bit, I just needed to use facet queries.

```
    facet.field=genre_id
```

(to get the distinct genre_ids with counts)

```
    facet.query=age_min:[*+TO+4] 
    facet.query=age_min:[4+TO+7]+AND+age_max:[7+TO+99]
    facet.query=age_min:[7+TO+10]+AND+age_max:[10+TO+99]
    facet.query=age_min:[13+TO+99]+AND+age_max:[13+TO+99]
```

(to get counts for each age range)

The result:

```
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{
      "age_min:[* TO 4]":6,
      "age_min:[4 TO 7] AND age_max:[7 TO 99]":16},
      ....
    "facet_fields":{
      "genre_id":[
        "818",740,
        "51",707,
        "1637",373,
       ....
```

I only wish I could give a 'name' to the facet_queries, but other than that this is my working solution.